# Automator Service with Google Translate

Tags: macos, automator, script

I set up an Automator Service that receives selected text and then runs a simple shell script to pass the text to open google translate:

```
open https://translate.google.com/#auto/en/"$@"
```

It opens google translate just fine, but doesn't pass the text along with it. How can I fix?

[google translate service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNg3p.png)

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me as long as pass input was set to as arguments. You could try restarting or creating a new identical service like that.

You have to URL encode the input though:

```
open https://translate.google.com/#auto/auto/$(ruby -rcgi -e 'print CGI.escape(STDIN.read)')
```

[image]

Or if you don't want to use ruby:

```
xxd -p | tr -d '\n' | sed 's/\(..\)/%\1/g'
```