# Quick entry for Google Translate via MacOS?

Tags: macos, automator, google

Is there a way to input text into a quick-entry form that takes that text to Google Translate, and then spit out a translation? You know how to-do list managers like OmniFocus and Things you can quickly add a to-do or when you press cmd-space for Spotlight Search? I have a feeling it would be through Automator, and saw the following question

[Automator Service with Google Translate](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/94512/automator-service-with-google-translate)

but its all greek to me! How would the UI look like?

Answer (score 1):

There are dashboard widgets that offer translation. https://www.apple.com/downloads/dashboard/travel/languagetranslator.html
Then I use a hot corner to quickly launch dashboard. It can also be done by a keyboard shortcut. [image]